# Android Studio can't find runner

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle, avd-manager

I cloned a project from git and built it in android studio without any problems but I don't have (Run app) in android studio and also when I run run-android I get this error:

```
Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`
```

but I can run my emulator from AVD manager!
I did every solutions that I found with search but they didn't work for me

[image]

Comment: What repo did you clone?

Comment: my company application, this is a private project

Comment: In that case I can just guess what‘s wrong.
Maybe there is in local.properties a SDK path defined which is not on your system.

Comment: thanks, it is a correct address, I can build my project and I get BUILD SUCCESSFUL also I can run my emulator from AVD manager, but Run app is disable!

Answer (score 50):

For me, the reason was one of the following:

- Gradle sync was in progress
- Gradle sync had failed
- Gradle *build.gradle[.kts]* had been modified

For the last two cases, go to your top-level or app build file and click `Try again` or `Sync` button on the notification shown at the top of the file.

You could also just try to [sync the IDE with Gradle](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/guide/tutorials/working-with-gradle/syncing-and-reloading/) with either of these buttons:

[image: Syncing IDE with Gradle]

Comment: Similar issue for me, I made a change to the build.gradle file and failed to click Sync. Once I did, the Run app button (green triangle) became enabled again.

Answer (score 5):

I faced a similar error. I was trying to import a built apk to profile it and ran into the scenario where the run button was grayed out.

Ultimately what worked. I went to `File > Manage IDE Settings > Restore default settings..` and **redid the `android studio` setup**.
Note: Doing this will **RESET** the entire `Android Studio` and **redownload everything**.

Answer (score 0):

1- Give the SDK path (to find the emulator path), Usually in User\YourUsername\AppData (is hidden by default)\Local\Android\Sdk. in File->Project structure, SDK location. Also the Java\Jdk path for (JDKs) and the path "...java\util\concurrent" exist
Do not reset the IDE Settings (because you need to reinstall a lot of things and it will not solve)
2 possibility - from File->Setting->Tools->Emulator to check the Launch in a tool window
3 possibility -