# IntelliJ id not showing Run button not able to click it ethier

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

[image]
Since I created a new project in another place it did not leting me run my code.

Comment: You need to add a run configuration. Or press the play button in the gutter next to the main method.

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html#run_app

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio can't find runner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69415378/android-studio-cant-find-runner)